# How to clasp pull to typescript file

Tags: typescript, clasp

I've been recently exploring how to develop in Apps Script using TypeScript and have been looking into various aspects of it.

The issue is that **when I send TypeScript files to Apps Script, clasp pushes them well. However, when I pull from AppScript through Clasp, it doesn't update the existing ts files but creates new js files instead.**

To make incremental changes to the code while debugging in the Apps Script editor, it would be more convenient if the pull worked properly.

https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/77
In this post, it was mentioned that gs -> ts pull support might not be available, but since a considerable amount of time has passed, I am curious to know if the situation has changed.

I've searched extensively but haven't found a solution.
Is this impossible, or is it just me experiencing this issue?

Thank you